# React : get Form values from children component on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, bind

**Resume:** I have a `SignForm` component that is used multiple times by parent components and I can't figured out a way to pass the `input values` from `SignForm` to the parent Component.

I already searched for it, found some similar questions but on my case it doesn't work :/

---

**Login** : the parent component that calls the SignForm

```
class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        //... code
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SignForm
                cta='Go'
                switchSign='Create account'
                handleSubmit={this._handleSubmit}
            />
        )
    }

    _handleSubmit(username, password) {
        console.log(username, password);
         this._validateUser(username, password);
    }

    _validateUser(username, password) {
        //....
    }
}
```

**SignForm** : the children component that contains the form markup

```
class SignForm extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        var self = this;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="Form" onSubmit={this._onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <div className="Form-body">
                    <p className="InputSide">
                        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" ref={(input) => this._username = input}/>
                        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                    </p>

                    <p className="InputSide">
                        <input id="password" type="pass" name="password" ref={(input) => this._password = input}/>
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div className="Form-footer">
                    <button type="submit" name="sign" className="BtnBasic--lg">{this.props.cta}</button>
                    <Link to="/login" className="Link">{this.props.switchSign}</Link>
                </div>
            </form>

       )
    }

    _onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this._username.value, this._password.value); //it logs the input values.
        self.props.handleSubmit(this._username.value, this._password.value); //error
    }
}
```

The view renders without problems displaying the props passed to SignForm. The problem is on the form submit: The last line `self.props.handleSubmit(this._username.value, this._password.value);` return an  error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSubmit' of undefined(…)"

Thanks.

Update: I found a solution, check my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40795900/4737729)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. It was a `this` and `.bind()` missing:

**1.** on `SignForm` I replaced the `self` on this line:

`self.props.handleSubmit(this._username.value, this._password.value);`

to `this`:

`this.props.handleSubmit(this._username.value, this._password.value);`

**2.** On `Login` I added to this line `.bind(this)`:

`handleSubmit={this._handleSubmit}`

to:

`handleSubmit={this._handleSubmit.bind(this)}`

---

**Conclusion:** I need to be more careful with the use of `this` and `.bind()`. I hope to help someone that might have the same problem as me.

Comment: Avoid [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) inside `render()`. We don't want `.bind` to create a new function on every re-render. Either bind your event handler in `constructor` or use [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to define them.

Comment: Thanks! Is it the same as jpdelatorre answer?

Comment: Yes, @jpdelatorre answer is an idiomatic and fair solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have functions inside your component other than the `constructor` and Component's lifecycle method (`render`, `componentWillMount`, `componentDidMount`, etc...), and you'll be using the `this` keyword to access class method or `props` or `state`, you'll need to `bind` the `this`. You can do so inside your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this._handleSubmit = this._handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

That way, you don't have to bind it on every caller...

`<form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit} />`

Comment: Oh i didn't know that. Thank you. Do u know any article about "quick tips/best practices" about React?